# Throw duplicatekeyexception in JPA/Hibernate/Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to migrate my code from JdbcTemplate to JPA. I am used to having `DuplicateKeyException` being thrown when an insert is being performed on a unqiue constraint. I was wondering how do I get JPA to throw a `DuplicateKeyException`? Or if there is a better alternative to throwing exceptions for duplicatekeys.

EDIT: 
The exception I usually get is `DataIntegrityViolationException` instead of `DuplicateKeyException`

Comment: You should be able to catch a Spring DataAccessException. Which db?

Comment: Can you check if you aren't affected by [SPR-11699](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11669) by any chance? That was an issue with H2 but maybe MySQL is throwing the same kind of invalid exception type.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to get any cause of database, translate the `sql error code` form `SQLException`. The code will be different base on underlying database.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088499/entitymanager-exception-handling-in-session-bean/13111029#13111029)